Continuity on the torus
Let $\mathbb{T}^d$ be the $d$-dimensional torus, for all $r >0,\eta_r(x):=e^{-r|x|^2},x \in \mathbb{R}^d,$ we denote by $\mathscr{F}^{-1}\eta_r$ the inverse Fourier transform defined by $\mathscr{F}^{-1}\eta_r(x):=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d}\eta_r(k)e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}\langle x,k\rangle},x \in \mathbb{T}^d.$ Let $v_0 \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^d),$
Is it true that $$\forall x \in \mathbb{T}^d,\lim_{r \to 0}\mathscr{F}^{-1}\eta_r*v_0(x)=v_0(x)?$$
I know how to prove this when we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^d:$ $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d,\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}v_0(x-y)\mathscr{F}^{-1}\eta_r(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathscr{F}^{-1}\eta_1(y)v_0(x-ry)dy$$ where we used a simple linear change of variable, we conclude using the dominated convergence theorem, that the limit is $v_0(x).$
How to treat the problem when we are on the torus? Unfortunately, the above change of variable won't work.

You define $\eta_r(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb T^d$ and then use $\eta_r(k)$ for $k\in \mathbb Z^d$. Can you clarify?

For a "minimalistic" formulation, I would define $F_r(x) := \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^d} e^{-r |k|^2} e^{2\pi \mathrm{i} \langle x, k \rangle}$ for $x\in \mathbb T^d$, and get rid of $\eta_r$.

For your change of variable in $\mathbb R^d$ to work, you would need the non-periodic inverse Fourier transform: $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \eta_r(x) = \int \eta_r(\xi) e^{2\pi \mathrm{i} \langle x, \xi\rangle} \mathrm d \xi$. This simplifies the analysis somewhat, because in the torus, there doesn’t seem to be any straightforward relationship between $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \eta_r$ and $\mathcal F^{-1} \eta_s$ for $s\neq r$.

Take the Fourier transform: for every $n\in \mathbb Z^d$, since the Fourier transforms changes convolution into product,
$$ \mathcal{F}\left( \mathcal F^{-1} \eta_r * v_0 \right)(n) = \eta_r(n) \mathcal F v_0(n) \to \mathcal F v_0(n) $$
as $r\to 0$.
Now, using the fact that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\mathcal F v_0(n)| < \infty$ (because $v_0$ is $C^{\infty}$, thus for every nonnegative integer $N$, $|\mathcal F v_0(k)|$ is smaller than some constant times $|k|^{-N}$) and that for every $n\in \mathbb Z^d$, $\eta_r(n)\to 1$ as $r\to 0$ with $|\eta_r(n)|\leq 1$ for every $r>0$, you can use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that as $r\to 0$,
$$ \mathcal F^{-1} \eta_r * v_0 (x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^d} e^{2\pi \mathrm{i} \langle x, n\rangle} \mathcal{F}\left( \mathcal F^{-1} \eta_r * v_0 \right)(n) 
\to \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z^d} e^{2\pi \mathrm{i} \langle x, n\rangle} \mathcal F v_0(n) = v_0(x) . $$
Note that this does not require the specific form of $\eta_r$: any function that is bounded by $1$ and converges to $1$ pointwise as $r\to 0$ works.
